# If Grace and her friends were to roll the two dice 100 times, how many of the 100 times could they expect to roll the same number on each die?

Tags: probability

need some help on this question I tried the question out but still don't understand

Answer (score 1):

The probability of both dice having the same number is $\frac{6}{36}$, as there are $36$ different outcomes, $6$ of which have two of the same number, i.e. $(1,1), (2,2),...$.

The expected number of rolls of this type in $100$ pairs of dice rolls is $100*\frac{6}{36}$

Answer (score 0):

It is like,

($1$ of grace and $1$ of his friend) or ($2$ of grace and $2$ of his friend) or ($3$ of grace and $3$ of his friend)...........

$\implies (\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}) + (\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}) $

$\implies 6 \times \frac{1}{36}$

$\implies \frac{1}{6} $

This means

If they roll $6$ times they get $1$ time the same

So,

If they roll $100$ times they get $\frac{100}{6}$ the same.